# Difference in Difference model: How to find the control group

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, difference-in-difference

I am conducting research on the effect on a regulation applied in Hong Kong. I am analyzing the impact of the exclusion of sales commission of investment products which caused a conflict of interests between financial advisors and clients (the financial advisors used to advise the products with highest commission instead of the best fit for the client). I want to analyze the impact on the net returns of mutual funds in that country pre and post the regulation (my guess is that they increase).

However, I am struggling to find the control group. I could not compare another country, not affected, because of different investment allocations, or I could?.

I know it's more a theoretical question, I would like to have more opinions.

Thank you!

Comment: Is your unit of analysis the *country*, or are you looking at firms *within* Hong Kong?

Comment: @ThomasBilach The Hang Seng stock market is likely the financial instrument referred to as a "country," and is likely the reason that Hong Kong has not been totally absorbed as a jurisdiction into a rather less organized conglomerate.